# Coldfusion - Cant find testbox

Tags: unit-testing, coldfusion, testbox

I have a coldfusion application that i would like to start writing unit tests for. I found testbox, and think it would be a great testing library to use. I followed the [installation instructions](https://testbox.ortusbooks.com/introduction/installing-testbox), but my cold fusion app is throwing an error when i try to run my first test. 
I downloaded the zip file and put in in my C drive, added the mapping to my application.cfc, but it throws the following error (see below). Can anyone help me debug why it can't find textbox?

Error

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 2 at column 1.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
testbox


The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/tests/main.cfc: line 2
1 : // Create TestBox object
2 : testbox = new testbox.system.TestBox();
3 : â€‹
4 : // You can add fluent specs via addDirectory(), addDirectories(), addBundles()
```

Application.cfc

```
component {
    this.name = "A TestBox Runner Suite " & hash( getCurrentTemplatePath() );
    // any other application.cfc stuff goes below:
    this.sessionManagement = true;

    // any mappings go here, we create one that points to the root called test.
    this.mappings[ "/tests" ] = getDirectoryFromPath( getCurrentTemplatePath() );
    // Map back to its root
    this.mappings[ "/testbox" ] = expandPath( "C:/testbox/" );

    // any orm definitions go here.

    // request start
    public boolean function onRequestStart( String targetPage ){
        return true;
    }
}
```

main.cfc

```
// Create TestBox object
testbox = new testbox.system.TestBox();
​
// You can add fluent specs via addDirectory(), addDirectories(), addBundles()
testbox.addDirectory( "specs" );
​
// Run tests and produce reporter results
testbox.run()
​
// Run tests and get raw testbox.system.TestResults object
testbox.runRaw()
​
// Run tests and produce reporter results from SOAP, REST, HTTP
testbox.runRemote()
```

test box directory. 
[image]

Comment: Try changing your mapping to `C:\testbox\testbox\ `, or move the contents of your `\testbox\testbox\` folder up one level. I think you may have unzipped to one too many folders. Is there a `system` folder inside the second `testbox` folder?

Comment: @Shawn, now, moving it up a directory did not help.

Comment: Are your TestBox files in `C:\testbox\ ` or `C:\testbox\testbox\ `? Or some other directory? Your mapping should point to the folder that contains the TestBox files.

Comment: @Shawn, i resolved the issue by doing the extraction you mentioned, and then creating a runner.cfm instead of a runner.cfc like in the docs.

Comment: @Shawn, put in an answer and get some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your mapping to `C:\testbox\testbox\` , or move the contents of your `\testbox\testbox` folder up one level. I think you may have unzipped to one too many folders. Is there a `system` folder inside the second `testbox` folder? You want to make sure that your mapping points to the folder containing your actual TestBox files.